# Storing XML with no Unique field

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting

I have a big xml file that I want to sort but I'm a little rusty on how to handle this case.

I have a big xml file with about 40k rows but this xml file has no unique element that I can use to sort after.

Is it possible to order by 2 elements so to speak?

```
<Customer>
   <row CompanyID="1" Name="John" Email="John@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="1" Name="Jane" Email="Jane@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="1" Name="Howard" Email="Howard@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="2" Name="Jen" Email="Jen@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="2" Name="James" Email="James@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="3" Name="Phil" Email="Phil@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="3" Name="Kenny" \>
   <row CompanyID="3" Name="Andrew" Email="Andrew@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="3" Name="Greg" Email="Greg@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="4" Name="Julia" Email="Julia@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="4" Name="Hannah" Email="Hannah@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="4" Name="Riley" Email="" \>
   <row CompanyID="4" Name="Anders" Email="Anders@mail.com" \>
</Customer>
```

Lets say I first start to order by the CompanyID, That is 11122333 and so on...
and the I also want to sort by lets say Email.
(Note that one email is missing)

that is first numerical with CompanyID and then alphabetically with email if exists.

Which would give me the result of (breaks are just for representation):

```
 <Customer>
   <row CompanyID="1" Name="Howard" Email="Howard@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="1" Name="Jane" Email="Jane@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="1" Name="John" Email="John@mail.com" \>

   <row CompanyID="2" Name="Bill" Email="Bill@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="2" Name="Jen" Email="Jen@mail.com" \>

   <row CompanyID="3" Name="Andrew" Email="Andrew@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="3" Name="Greg" Email="Greg@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="3" Name="Phil" Email="Phil@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="3" Name="Kenny" \>

   <row CompanyID="4" Name="Anders" Email="Anders@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="4" Name="Hannah" Email="Hannah@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="4" Name="Julia" Email="Julia@mail.com" \>
   <row CompanyID="4" Name="Riley" Email="" \>
</Customer>
```

Also Note that one Email attributes is missing completely and another is just empty.

Right now it's just sorting by "CompanyID" which gives me 111223333... and so on.

```
            var xml = xDoc.Element("Customer")
            .Elements("row")
            .OrderBy(s => (int)s.Attribute("CompanyID"));
```

The reason I need to sort by Email also, is that Emails are unique in this case, the bad thing is that they aren't in every record so to speak.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`ThenBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var xml = xDoc.Element("Customer")
        .Elements("row")
        .OrderBy(s => (int)s.Attribute("CompanyID"))
        .ThenBy(s =>string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)s.Attribute("Email"))?"ZZZ":(string)s.Attribute("Email"));
```

Using the conditional operator you can use a default value (eg,"ZZZ") to to put the elements with `Email` attribute empty and without `Email` attribute at the end of the result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answere. Does that work even though the Email is completely missing? @octavioccl

Comment: Yes, if the email is not there, then the attribute method should return null, so  due to the coalescing operator that element is going to be at the end of the result because it uses "ZZZ" value to order those cases

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out as soon as i'm home again. :)

Comment: I changed the boolean operator because I noticed the` Email`attribute could be there but could be empty, in that case the result of casting will be an empty string, and null coalescing operator (??) work with null value

Comment: ok, I noticed that if i write the same thing with a casting to and int instead on a casting to a string the "??" doesn't work if it applies to the same criteria of which the int value is missing and such.